# Python CSV writer script syntax

Tags: python, csv

Who wants to help out a newbie? I keep getting either Indent errors or when I manage correct indentation I end up with an IO error because the file is already automatically closed by the Open With. What am I doing wrong?

This is my script;

```
 import csv

 infile = ('Test')

 with open(infile+'.txt') as csvfile, open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
     lines = sorted(set(line.strip('\n').lower() for line in csvfile))
 for line in lines:
       writer = csv.writer(outfile, lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: I attempted to update your formatting, but you should probably make sure that the edited version looks like your code if we're trying to help you with indentation errors

Comment: It always help if you add the exact error text to your questions. Python is quite verbose in that – and every bit helps us help you. Indentation errors in such short programs are easy to fix – just follow the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Indent the code to write out under the with statement.
You had a few spaces in there as well that were throwing out the indentation. I flattened your code then indented it out. You'll probably have to either open as read-write or open once to read and then once to write.

```
import csv

infile = ('Test')

with open(infile+'.txt') as csvfile, open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    lines = sorted(set(line.strip('\n').lower() for line in csvfile))
    for line in lines:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Its also possible that the indents are _my_ mistake - OP's original was inline so I may have messed up the original when I tried to format it

Comment: Thank you both! Code is now working... only when I print to screen I see the expected output and when I use csv.writer I get an , after every single character, how can I solve that?

Comment: It's either reading or writing. Either you're reading text with nothing as the delimiter or writing with nothing as the delimiter. I suggest checking the data file and explicitly setting the delimiters for reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the formatting on the original question. If my edit did not somehow mess things up, the likely issue is that by opening and closing both `infile` and `outfile` in the same `with` block you have already closed `outfile` when you want to write to it.

If you rearrange it like this it may be more predictable

```
import csv

infile = ('Test')

with open(infile+'.txt') as csvfile:
     lines = sorted(set(line.strip('\n').lower() for line in csvfile))

with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for line in lines:
        writer.writerow(line)
```